# package-user-dir Invalid function: convenience

Tags: emacs

I keep this line in my `.emacs` file to synchronize installed packages across computers:

```
(setq package-user-dir "~/Dropbox/Log/elpa")
```

This works on computer A, but on computer B, I get an `Invalid function: convenience` error. This is what I get back when I run `--debug-init`.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function "convenience")
  "convenience"("vc" "git")
  byte-code("\300\301\302\303\304\305\306\307\310\311\312\"&\207" [define-package "git-commit-mode" "20140605.520" "Major mode for editing git commit messages" nil :url "https://github.com/magit/git-modes" :keywords "convenience" "vc" "git"] 11)
  load("c:/Users/username/Dropbox/Log/elpa/git-commit-mode-20140605.520/git-commit-mode-pkg" nil t)
  package-load-descriptor("~/Dropbox/Log/elpa" "git-commit-mode-20140605.520")
  package-maybe-load-descriptor("git-commit-mode" "20140605.520" "~/Dropbox/Log/elpa")
  package-load-all-descriptors()
  package-initialize()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-681561> nil "c:/Users/username/Dropbox/Log/elisp/main.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 242
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/username/Dropbox/Log/elisp/main.el" "c:/Users/username/Dropbox/Log/elisp/main.el" nil nil)
  load("c:/Users/username/Dropbox/Log/elisp/main.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/Dropbox/Log/elisp/main.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/username/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 42
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/username/.emacs.d/init.el" "c:/Users/username/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("c:/Users/username/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of Emacs do you have on computer B?  The following [bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-02/msg00169.html) may be relevant.

Comment: When sharing packages between different Emacs installations, please make sure that you are using the same major release on all installations.  *Installed* packages are not generally compatible across major releases, for multiple reasons.

Comment: I am using major version 24 on both A and B. Computer B specifically has 24.3.1.